# Nested RecyclerView's height to “wrap_content” with a large amount of items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view, android-scrollview, nestedrecyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` nested in a vertical scrolling view. The `RecyclerView` displays items with a vertical `LinearLayoutManager`. Its height is (and has to be, per product specification) set to `wrap_content`.

Problem is memory and performance issues come around quickly when I set a large amount (~50+) because items are simply not recycled.

What is the good way to make this work nicely and smoothly?

**Edit:** Ok, some more details.

I have to make screen that describes a TV show: the synopsis, the list of seasons, and for each season the list of episodes. The list of episodes for each season must not be collapsed/folded/shrinked.

This is what I have to achieve:

[image]

Comment: RecyclerView never loaded for 50+ items at one time. They use the minimum amount of views that need to be loaded when user scrolling. (threadhold)

Comment: @PhátPhát the height of the RecyclerView is not limited, so it is as big as there are items, and so it will load all items at once.

Comment: You need to read documentation again https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Comment: You say it's height "has to be, per product specification" `wrap_content`. Can you elaborate? I'd be very surprised if a customer asked for specific xml attribute values. Maybe you could explain the overall UI you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, I edited my post with an image.

Comment: @riot Found any solution? I'm dealing with the same kind of problem now. RecyclerView loads all items once because of wrap_content and it freezes the UI.

Comment: @muthuraj The solution I found is to use a unique RecyclerView with different row types. In my example the RV will display the "Lorem ipsum..." text as first view, "Season 1" as second view, "Episode" as third view, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you have a scrolling view inside a scrolling view. Apply `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` to your `RecyclerView`.